# How to use a specific button in doInBackground of Android?

Tags: android, google-maps, button

I am using google maps for my android app. I have created a button on the graphic layout on top of the google maps activity, but I only want that button to become visible when I am in range of a marker on my map. I have created a void checking method that is in my doInBackground whether or not I am in range, but I do not know how to specifically call the button that is on the graphic layout. How would I call the button?

Comment: Why do you need to do anything in background when just checking if you are in range of some other location?

Comment: If the checking method is true, it makes the button visible. If the checking is false, it makes the button invisible.

Comment: You didn't understand me. I'm asking why do you even need `AsyncTask` to do this?

Comment: I'm not sure where else to do it.

Comment: How about in [`onLocationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29) or [`onLocationChanged`](http://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationListener.html#onLocationChanged%28android.location.Location%29)?

Answer (score 0):

I the `doInBackground` you can't do UI stuff. You would have to do in the UI thread. I would have said that you can use `runOnUIThead` function within the background thread, but background thread and execute even when your UI is not present. So this might not be best idea.

When you are in range of marker, you can send a `LocalBroadcast` which will be received by the activity if its in the foreground. Then it can take actions based on that. See [how to use LocalBroadcastManager?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8802157/how-to-use-localbroadcastmanager) for how to use it. This again is one of the other many options.

On another thought, you can send a message from `doInBackGround` to `onProgressUpdate` whenever you get in the range of the marker. From there you can still update the UI.

Comment: How would I communicate between the doInBackGround to the onProgressUpdate? Should I make a variable in doInBackGround and then call the same variable in onProgressUpdate?

Comment: Best way to learn that would to be to read the basic of AsyncTask firs. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

Comment: You can pass a result from `doInbackground` to the other two functions easily. Hope for found it on that link.